# How to write this if in the right way in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, radio-button

I need a way to do this "if" in the radio buttons to show me in the users blade what rights have the specific user im edditing

```
 @if($users->home_elv_rights == 5)
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ Form::radio('userRights',0,true) }}
                    Candidate
                </label>


                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ Form::radio('userRights',1,false) }}
                    Student
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ Form::radio('userRights',2,false) }}
                    Teacher
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ Form::radio('userRights',3,false) }}
                    Manager
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ Form::radio('userRights',4,false) }}
                    Co worker
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{ Form::radio('userRights',5,false) }}
                    Director / Ceo
                </label>

                @endif
```

My way will repeat the whole buttons code 6 times i need a better way to do this

**SOLVED**

Both answers are correct hope this helps someone else too !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your model this constant:

```
const USER_RIGHTS=['Candidate','Student','Teacher','Manager','Co-worker','Director'];
```

after that, add this code to your view:

```
@foreach(User::USER_RIGHTS as $index=>$role)
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
     {{ Form::radio('userRights', $index, ($users->home_elv_rights == $index ? true : false)) }}
     {{ $role }}
  </label>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

`@for` should work. In the controller:

```
$rolesArray = array('Candidate', 'Student', 'Teacher', 'Manager', 'Co worker', 'Director / Ceo');
```

In the view:

```
@for($i=0; $i < 6; $i++)
    {{ $checked = $i == $users->home_elv_rights ? true : false }}
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
         {{ Form::radio('userRights', $i, $checked) }}
         {{ $rolesArray[$i] }}
    </label>
@endfor
```

Thanks to **Praveen Kumar** for help.

Comment: `$i <= 6` should be `$i <= 5` **for 6 times only**

Comment: i need to enter the edit blade of the user and show me for the specific $id the Checked button....` @if($users->home_elv_rights == 5)` it shows me the user Owner check the button !

Comment: So, if it's 5, then button number 5 should be checked?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin exactly!

Comment: Okay it workes if i put it in the controller but its not checked maybe u know why ?

Comment: Maybe `$users->home_elv_rights` returns string, not integer. Try to use `==` instead of `===`

Comment: No @AlexeyMezenin there is not string in the this column in the the users table i just checked... :(

Comment: [link](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/168/creating-a-radio-button-input-field) I started from this .....maybe the convertion to laravel is not right.... :S

Comment: It can be 5 as string and not 5 as integer (I mean it can look like integer, but be a string). If you didn't try `==`, please try.

Comment: Nop the table only acceptes integer as home_elv_rights but thx u both showed me a different way but dont work cause of something else maybe @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: It's really interesting where is the problem. Can you post output of `dd($users->home_elv_rights)` please?

Comment: Thx a lot @AlexeyMezenin it works your too , just adjusting the color cause of the stupid screen didnt know the difference sorry about that , and thanks both for showing me this method ! I will use it soon !